# Volume Mixer automatically mutes game

Tags: windows-7, audio, mute, mixer

I am running a game (3d movie maker) and the Volume mixer has set the sound right down to 0. 
So I put the volume back up, but as soon as I click back to the game, the volume goes right back down again.

I've read similar problems, but this isn't related to running multiple applications. This only happens with this one game. And this problem happened randomly, after I put the volume down myself. After that one occasion I haven't been able to fix it.

Communications setting is set to "do nothing" and I have played with options allowing applications exclusive control of volume mixer.

Any ideas please?

I am using Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: What operating system do you use? Please [edit] your post and include a proper tag.

Comment: Have you tried system restore back to a date prior to the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately system restore had not set any previous restore points, so that's out.